# google adsense : this is weird for me the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Tags: javascript, php, ads, adsense

I'm New in Google Adsence and having trouble till 2 days, I have create my account on google adsence follow all the step as given in docs, but cant display ad it will shows blank space instead of google adsence I couldn't found any solution.

Here my code is:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead /js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Large Scrapper -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-3854574222872233"
        data-ad-slot="5224881302"></ins>
     <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Please Help me to resolve my issue

Comment: did you added jQuery library befor this code?

Comment: Yes , added jquery library but problem not solved

Answer (score 1):

- Are you sure you don't use adblock tool in your browser.
- Try other internet browser.
- Check if on your page is any javascript error which could block advert loading.

Comment: no i use adblock in chrome but it is in disable mode now.  no any other javascript error to display . only shows status 403 in console when the page load.

Comment: It looks like you page is banned for AdSense crawler. Try to generate new adsense code, disable CDN service if there is any, try tips to solve 403 from [link](https://www.shoutmeloud.com/adsense-403-forbidden-error.html)